# Can "to" mean "that will"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I recently wrote something like this:

> "You have reached [name of company], the hand that will catch you before jumping off [some marketing metaphor]."

A native English speaker suggested the following edit:

> "You have reached [name of company], the hand **to** catch you before jumping off [some marketing metaphor]."

I think **to** in this case, more or less, means **that will** like in the original version of the text. Or maybe I'm wrong and it means something else? Or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, they mean roughly the same, it is just that the action is different. "the hand that will" suggest that the action is on your part, "the hand to catch" suggest that the jumper can call on you for help at the moment they jump.

The best one depends on your target audience.

Comment: I see. So "that will" is more active than "to" (and "to" is a more passive action)?

Comment: No, it is the difference between "we will" and "we could, if you want"